# Trigger state change of a React component from Chrome extension on a Facebook post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, google-chrome, plugins

I'm doing a Chrome plugin for Facebook and I want to modify a post using external javascript. I can change the textContent of a span but the state is not changed and the Save button is not activated.

[image: Facebook Post]

The html looks like that :

```html
<div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="1477r" data-offset-key="a699d-0-0">
  <div data-offset-key="a699d-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj">
    <span data-offset-key="a699d-0-0">
      <span data-text="true">test</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The component in React Developper Tools : 
[[image: React component[2]]

I profiled a change of the text and this is the result for a 6 ms timeline activating the save button.
[image: `Profiling]

There are ways to modify a React input but did not found ways for my problem :

- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11488
- https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10135#issuecomment-314441175

How can you change a Facebook post and his state with external javascript?

What would you do?

Comment: What stops you from using the methods from these links?

Comment: It'a not an input but a span.

Comment: That’s because they’re using draft js, draft js uses content editable for the editor. There’s a few posts about simulating input in draft js / content editable, but I don’t have time to verify they work.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/325#issuecomment-300372428

Comment: This question probably isn't going to get a satisfactory answer because it's not possible. Instead, please give us more information so we can find an alternative that is possible. What is your overall goal here, as in, why is someone editing a post?

Answer (score -1):

That’s not possible, you can’t imperatively mutate a React element tree from outside the app. You’d have to declaratively render a tree, either by modifying Facebook’s frontend code (beware of legal ramifications) or implementing your own post UI.

Comment: Is there any kind of doc about this?

Comment: The react dev tools access state via the chrome extension, so it is totally possible and actually being done in production.

Comment: There's a huge difference between what the devtools protocol supports and what can be done by browser JS (including JS interjected by an extension). The devtools integrations are designed by devtools, as far as I'm aware there's no public API you can use for this.

Comment: That's wrong, react devtools uses a global on the window object that react then connects to. You can see the source code for that here: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/08c1f79e1e13719ae2b79240bbd8f97178ddd791/packages/react-devtools-extensions/src/injectGlobalHook.js

It's also mentioned in the README for old repo for the extension: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/tree/v3

Comment: So - you can totally connect to the full react state via that with an extension.

Comment: With a DEVTOOLS extension. This is Facebook, which is not part of devtools. This isn't meant for anything else.

Answer (score -1):

While it's nearly impossible to change the state of *React* component from your plugin, nothing stops you from emulating user's input by sending keystrokes, mouse clicks etc. The only thing you need it to figure out - which DOM-element listens to these events (not necessary one of those 4 in you question).

---

About the possibility of direct state change: let's say the component you need to changes is a functional one. Then it has a form of

```
Component() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(...)
  ...
  setState(something)
  ...
}
```

so you need to somehow access the `setState` function of the component. But how? It's private to the function call. If you think that instead you can call the  `useState` directly, then be aware that in *another* component it will return *another* `setState`. I have no idea what would happen if you'll call `useState` outside of a component, but surely it will not be able to guess which `setState` you want.

If you want you can check the source code of *react-devtools* to find out how you can dig out the state from the depths of *React*... but would you really want to try? And for what? The next time *Facebook* or *React* will be updated your code will definitely break.

Comment: IIRC it’s actually not that hard to access the state from a chrome extension. Proof is that the react dev tools do exactly that. That said, this is better solved by simulating input.

Comment: @ibash *react-devtools* are made by facebook, it's no surprise that they can access the state. But you're right, I'll rephrase my answer.